# handle CONNECT requests in a websocket server

Tags: websocket

My websocket server listens on port 8080 with no proxy.
Most of the time I'm getting requests with the Upgrade Websocket header and it works fine.

Sometimes I'm getting HTTP CONNECT requests.
Is this a valid request?
Does it means that there is a proxy server between the client and the server?
How my server is suppose to respond to the CONNECT request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting CONNECT requests because you are likely to have configured your browser to use a proxy. If you directed your browser to use port 8080 on your local IP address, it will assume there is a proxy and that means when you ask for a secure connection, the browser leads with CONNECT.

You will need to add support for SSL/TLS tunnelling to your server to deal with this.